# A required device isn't connected windows 10

Tags: window, windows-error-reporting

What are the  possible causes and how to fix?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

0xc000000f is usually due to missing BCD file that the bootmanager is looking for, and as its unable to find it it throws this error message.

Best thing to do would be boot the machine using a windows ISO or bootstick.

Then work through the screens until "Repair my computer" shows up in the bottom left of the screen.

Once you get into the repair options, your looking for the one marked "Start Up Repair"

This will scan your system and attempt to correct the bootmanager issue.

Comment: if the repair works, time to make a backup just incase somthing is wrong with that hardware.